# Partial EF Context OnModelCreating Using Scaffold-DbContext

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using doing database first development and using Scaffold-DbContext to create my entity models project. In that project, I have a partial dbContext where I override methods like SaveChangesAsync to set certain properties like, "LastModifiedBy".

I'm looking to soft-delete records using dateDeleted/userDeleted columns. When I go to override the OnModelCreating routine, I see that it's already defined on the auto-generated partial context.

I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<SomeEntity>().HasQueryFilter(x => x.DateDeleted == null);
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestion as to how I can do this in a partial class way that still allows me to regenerate the original context on the fly using Scaffold-DbContext?

Also note, I'm using .NET Core 2.1.5

**ANSWER FROM David Browne - Microsoft**

Add a static property on the partial context

```
public static bool GlobalFiltersAdded { get; set; } = false;
```

Then add a routine to add your filters:

```
private void AddGlobalFilters(ModelBuilder modelBuilder){
    SomeContext.GlobalFiltersAdded = true;
}
```

Then in your generated context add the following:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    AddGlobalFilters(modelBuilder);
    //OTHER LOGIC WILL BE HERE
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options:

1) Delete the generated OnModelCreating after re-scaffolding.  It's already a manual process, and generates a compile error if you forget.

2) Use a DbContext inherited from the generated DbContext.

3) Use a 3rd party tool or library like: [EF Core Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.EFCorePowerTools)

Comment: Good idea, that's what I ended up with. Added a method private void AddGlobalFilters(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) and added a single public static bool GlobalFiltersAdded { get; set; } = false;. In my SaveChanges routine, I check the existance of that property and throw an exception if not set.